# Brilliant Intellij feature replaces item.charAt(0) with item[0] ... but what is it?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

After I upgraded to the new version, I noticed the code has "changed".

Well ... the actually code didn't change but what was previously:

```
 item.charAt(0)
```

was replaced with:

```
 item[0]
```

as well as other some other changes.

If I hover over `item[0]`, a tooltip pops up showing the real value.

It is slick and a nice surprise (!) and I have no idea what it is called or how to cause it to fine tune it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the [Advanced Java Folding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9320-advanced-java-folding) plug-in. Either disable the plug-in or change its setting to not fold certain code elements.